# Alamofire .post in Swift. "Result of call is unused, but produces 'DataRequest'

Tags: xml, swift, interface-builder, cocoapods, alamofire

Trying to post some XML. Created an IBAction "SelectButtonA", which uses Alamofire.request to post to an address. Soap Encoding handled by a struct.

Doesn't work. How can I test that it's posting, and resolve the error "Result of call is unused, but produces a 'DataRequest'?

// Main struct that defines the SOAP encoding and XML for Alamofire. //

```
struct SOAPEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    let service: String
    let action: String
    let IRCCC: String = "AAAAAQAAAAEAAABlAw=="

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()

        guard parameters != nil else { return urlRequest }

        if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest.setValue("text/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPACTION") == nil {
            urlRequest.setValue("\(service)#\(action)", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPACTION")
        }

        //let soapArguments = parameters.map({key, value in "<\(key)>\(value)</\(key)>"}).joined(separator: "")

        let soapMessage =
            "<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' s:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>" +
                "<s:Body>" +
                "<u:\(action) xmlns:u='\(service)'>" +
                IRCCC +
                "</u:\(action)>" +
                "</s:Body>" +
        "</s:Envelope>"

        urlRequest.httpBody = soapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        return urlRequest
    }
}

@IBAction func SelectButtonA(sender: NSButton) {
    Alamofire.request("http://192.168.2.7/sony/IRCC?", method: .post, parameters: ["parameter" : "value"], encoding: SOAPEncoding(service: "urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1", action: "X_SendIRCC"))
}
```

[Screenshot of the whole thing. Trying to make a remote.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4641d.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is all explained in the Alamofire README on GitHub.

The `Alamofire.request()` method returns a `Request` object and starts it running. You can then use the `.response()` function On it to get the results of that request.

```
Alamofire.request(...).response {
    response in

    // get details of the result out of the response input to this closure.
}
```

Part one... how do you know it worked? Access the data in the completion.

Part two... how do you get rid of the error? Add the completion.

Comment: I checked the response. It's producing a malformed request. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

"Result of call is unused, but produces a 'DataRequest' is just a warning message because Alamofire.request(...) return a valuable but you didn't use it, not error message.

Answer (score 0):

Produced a malformed request.

The code that works to send a SOAP request, without headers etc.:

```
    Alamofire.request("http://192.168.2.7/sony/IRCC?",
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: ["parameter" : "value"],
                      encoding: SOAPEncoding(service: "urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1",
                                             action: "X_SendIRCC", IRCCC: "AAAAAQAAAAEAAABgAw==")).responseString { response in
                                                print(response)
```